# Using urlencode in script

Tags: php, curl, urlencode

I've been working on a script that can be used for an internal wiki, that will remove the properties for a user who is inactive. I believe I'm almost there but having a problem with the api.

I think I need to use *urlencode* on the $delete path BUT only for the @ in the email address and # in the property. I know how to use urlencode for the whole thing but not on just that. The way it works, is it loops through to get the properties and most of them include # in the name. Anyone who can help modify so that this works would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the script:

```
 <?php

    $user_id="john_smith@ourwiki.com";

    $url=('http://admin:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/users/=john_smith@ourwiki.com/properties');
    $xmlString=file_get_contents($url);

    $delete = "http://admin:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/DELETE:users/$user_id/properties/%s";
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

     function curl_fetch($url,$username,$password,$method='DELETE')
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // returns output as a string instead of echoing it
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password"); // if your server requires basic auth do this
        return  curl_exec($ch);
    }

    foreach($xml->property as $property) {
      $name = $property['name']; // the name is stored in the attribute
      curl_fetch(sprintf($delete, $name),'admin','12345');
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Does this line work?: `$xmlString=file_get_contents($url);`. If it does, the URL is valid.

Comment: cant you just use str_replace if you know what you want to encode it into?

Comment: @SimpleCoder It does but the problem is that the delete api isn't working. When I ran a separate CURL command using the urlencoded version it deleted the property as desired. But when it was not encoded it gave me a 404 error and couldn't complete.

Comment: @Sabeen maybe, i just wasn't sure how to do it best. See I just need to make the @ inside $user_id and the # inside property to be urlencoded. And the property changes as it goes through the loop to get all properties for individual user

Comment: Does anyone have an idea? I'm only really concerned with encoding the properties as it runs through the for loop. How can I make it so only the '#' is encoded within the property? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$delete = "http://admin:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/DELETE:users/".urlencode($user_id)."/properties/%s";
```